# Where do I put SENDER_ID for phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-pushplugin

phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0 "PushPlugin"

I updated phonegap-plugin-push to 2.0.0.
And on the documentation it says

"As of version 2.0.0 the SENDER_ID parameter has been removed at install time. Instead you put your google-services.json (Android) and/or GoogleService-Info.plist in the root folder of your project and then add the following lines into your config.xml."

So in my config.xml, I have:

[image]

[image]

And I also created those files to my project folder:

[image]

But then I don't know what to write in those two files!
I want to write SENDER_ID="1234567" in those files, but in what format?

The doc doesn't have an example for putting in SENDER_ID on those files.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write those file on your own!!

In my case, I use FCM to send push notifications and I downloaded them from the FCM portal. Are you using FCM or something else? Anyway, those files have to be downloaded.

Which push service do you use? FCM, Azure,..?

Further, with the push plugin 2.0.0, make sure you use the phonegap versione "cli-7.0.1".

Comment: I use GCM (I need to change to FCM I think!). And as you said, I should've downloaded those files! The link was this one. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592

Answer (score 0):

For the version 2.x, you don't need to add the SENDER_ID while installing the plugin. The plugin parses its own from the Google-service.json and google-service.info.plist file

simply install the plugin using the command

> ionic Cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push

and after that

> npm-install